# if I install JDK do I also need to install JRE

Tags: jdk, jre

if I install JDK 1.7 do I also need to install JRE 1.7 to support Tomcat?
I have installed the openJDK package and that seems to include JRE.
java -version shows that java 1.7 has been installed

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to install JRE then, as JDK usually consists of both development & run-time environments in it. If you install JDK then JRE will already be packaged in it and installed automatically along with JDK.

Generally to do `javac <filename.java>`, you need to have JDK which already has JRE in it. To do `java  filename` you need only JRE.